# Waiting for other pc to come up before mounting samba share

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba

I am mounting a samba share via /etc/fstab.
My problem is, if they are shutdown and I start them the machine who mounts the share is up first, and therefore the share is not yet available.
Is there a option that he trys to mount it till the share is available?

The problem is, that on these shares are data which applications need to run propperly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mount it automatically via fstab, use a crontab instead:

1. Set your `fstab` to not mount the share automatically

   ```
   //servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  noauto  0  0
   ```

   You can have various other options there, presumably you already do. The important part is to add the `noauto` which ensures that

   ```
         noauto do not mount when "mount -a"  is  given  (e.g.,  at  boot
                time)
   ```
2. Create a cron job that runs every minute and mounts the share if it isn't already mounted. Add this line to `/etc/crontab`

   ```
   * * * * *   root    mount | grep windowsshare || mount /media/windowsshare
   ```

That way, the disk will be mounted as soon as it's available.

---

For more fine grained control, you can write a script that i) checks whether the server is online and ii) mounts the share unless it's mounted. You could then run the script via cron:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
hostname_or_ip_address="1.2.3.4" ## add your WIndows host's name or IP here
if ping -c 1 -W 1 "$hostname_or_ip_address" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  mount | grep windowsshare || mount /media/windowsshare
fi
```

Save that script as `/usr/bin/check_mount` or whatever you please, make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/bin/check_mount` and then add this line to `/etc/crontab`

```
* * * * *   root   /usr/bin/check_mount
```

---

Another option worth looking into is [`autofs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs) which mounts systems on demand as soon as anyone tries to access them.